# Numpy---How to substitute by certain multi-elements in array at the same time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem during substitution with data in array:
say,

```
a = [1, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0]
c = [0, 0]
X = numpy.zeros((3, 3, 2))
```

and I have Matrix `Y` with shape (2,3,2) and it is non a zero matrix

Now; I want to equal these elements of X by Y directly;

```
X[tuple(numpy.where(a==0)[0]), 
  tuple(numpy.where(b==0)[0]),
  tuple(numpy.where(c==0)[0])] = Y
```

I got the error `shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

Comment: Does `Y` have shape (3,3,2) instead of (2,3,2)?

Comment: No, Y = [[[  0.  48.]
  [ 27.  27.]
  [ 44.  44.]]

 [[  0.   0.]
  [ 44.  44.]
  [  0.  43.]]]

Comment: size of Y is (2,3,2). And I wanna replace it in X but in certain places

Comment: Also note that `numpy.where([1,0,0]==0)` results in `(array([], dtype=int64),)` while  `numpy.where(numpy.array([1,0,0])==0)`  provides the actually intended `(array([1, 2]),)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to construct index arrays appropriate for indexing `X`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2016)
a=np.array([1, 0, 0])
b=np.array([0, 0, 0])
c=np.array([0, 0])
X = np.zeros((3,3,2))
Y = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2,3,2))

idx = np.ix_(a==0, b==0, c==0)
X[idx] = Y
print(X)
```

yields

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 9.,  8.],
        [ 3.,  7.],
        [ 4.,  5.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.],
        [ 9.,  9.]]])
```

---

Alternatively, you could construct a boolean mask

```
mask = (a==0)[:,None,None] & (b==0)[None,:,None] & (c==0)[None,None,:]
X[mask] = Y
```

Indexing `(a=0)` as in  `(a==0)[:,None,None]` [adds new axes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9510252/190597) to the 1D boolean array `(a=0)`. `(a==0)[:,None,None]` has shape (3,1,1). Similarly, `(b==0)[None,:,None]` has shape (1,3,1), and `(c==0)[None,None,:]` has shape (1,1,2).

When combined with `&` (bitwise-and), the three arrays are [broadcasted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to one common shape, (3,3,2). Thus, `X` gets indexed by one boolean array of shape (3,3,2) in

```
X[mask] = Y
```

Comment: Thanks a million but, is there any way to do in case Y has (2,3,2) size . what I am saying is that if Y has different size of X what can I do to store it into X ?

Comment: Thanks a million again and again, it works well...... I said X[mask]=Y .... and it works good