# How to convert a list to 2 d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I am using a function X , that takes `np.ndarray, shape=(num_pairs, 2), dtype=int` values . 
I have just a list `l=[a,b]` and I want to give this list to the above function X as input.

I get the error as * l must be ndim 2. You supplied 1 *

Is there any way around to submit this list to the function ?

Answer (score -1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511135/1062499).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([1,2])
>>> l
array([1, 2])
>>> l.shape
(2,)
>>> l.ndim
1
>>> l[None, :].shape
(1, 2)
>>> l[None, :].ndim
2
```

Comment: If all you have is a reference to another answer, please vote to close the question as a duplicate of that one.