# sklearn: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 99]

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, spyder, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to build a simple regression line with pandas in spyder.
After executing the following code, I got this error:

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 99]
```

the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Phil.csv')

x = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(x, y)
```

I think I know what is the problem, but I'm not quite sure how to deal with the syntax.
In the variable explorer, the size of x (and y) is (99L,), and from what I remember it can't be a vector, and it must be size (99,1).
same thing for y.

Saw a bunch of related topics, but none of them helped.

Comment: `y` can just be `(99,)` (need not be of shape `(99,1)`), but X must be a 2-d shape. Try `x = x.reshape(-1,1)` before fitting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referring to the sklearn documentation for `LinearRegression` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit), the `X` vector needs to conform to the specification `[n_samples,n_features]`.

Since you have only a single feature with many samples, the shape should be (99,1) - e.g., a single value per "row" with a single "column".

There are many ways to accomplish this (ref: [Efficient way to add a singleton dimension to a NumPy vector so that slice assignments work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510252/efficient-way-to-add-a-singleton-dimension-to-a-numpy-vector-so-that-slice-assig)), in your case, the following should work:

```
regressor.fit(x[:, None], y)
```

Don't forget that `predict` requires the same shape to the data!

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue as well.

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [20, 10]
```

I found a solution though. For my case the order of the splitting was not correct

I did

```
X_train, X_test, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=1/3, random_state=0)
```

instead of :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=1/3, random_state=0)
```

Hope it helps future coders who run into similar errors.