# Raising dimension of an array using np.squeeze equivalent

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use a `np.squeeze` equivalent for raising the dimension of `A` from `(1,3)` to `(1,1,3)`. Does there exist such an equivalent?

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(A.shape)
```

Comment: `A[None, :]` or `A[:, None, :]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to add a singleton dimension to a NumPy vector so that slice assignments work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510252/efficient-way-to-add-a-singleton-dimension-to-a-numpy-vector-so-that-slice-assig)

Answer (score 1):

Use `reshape` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html))

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
print(A.shape)  # (1, 3)
B = A.reshape((1, 1, 3))
print(B.shape)  # (1, 1, 3)
```